# Text input parser in c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file of this format:

```
L O A D   C A S E   1   O F   2  ...     
J O I N T   D I S P L A C E M E N T S                   (global)
      Joint    X-dsp       Y-dsp       Z-dsp       X-rot       Y-rot       Z-rot
         1    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        -0.001712
         2    0.000646   -0.021756    0.0         0.0         0.0        -0.001339
         3    0.003562   -0.038487    0.0         0.0         0.0        -0.000727
         4    0.006478   -0.041661    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.000104
         5    0.009536   -0.036266    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.000720
         6    0.012595   -0.022824    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.001326
         7    0.014724    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.001948
         8    0.010000   -0.018686    0.0         0.0         0.0        -0.001117
         9    0.009354   -0.036887    0.0         0.0         0.0        -0.000829
        10    0.005767   -0.041661    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.000060
        11    0.002180   -0.035866    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.000798
        12    0.000051   -0.020695    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.001210
    M E M B E R   E N D   F O R C E S                   (local)
      Member Joint      Nx          Vy         Vz         Txx        Myy        Mzz
         1      1    -16.138t      0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.011
         1      2     16.138t     -0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.017
         2      2    -72.907t      0.003      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.013
         2      3     72.907t     -0.003      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.023
         3      3    -72.909t     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.009
         3      4     72.909t      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.005
         4      4    -76.455t     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.007
         4      5     76.455t      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.003
         5      5    -76.453t     -0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.010
         5      6     76.453t      0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.000
         6      6    -53.226t     -0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.018
         6      7     53.226t      0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.008
         7      1    108.570c     -0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.011
         7      8   -108.570c      0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.004
         8      2    -76.765t     -0.004      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.024
         8      8     76.765t      0.004      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.021
         9      2     80.278c     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.006
         9      9    -80.278c      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.000
        10      3    -39.997t     -0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.014
        10      9     39.997t      0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.016
        11      4    -23.720t     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.004
        11      9     23.720t      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.007
        12      4     -0.001t      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.002
        12     10      0.001t     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.001
        13      4    -18.706t      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.003
        13     11     18.706t     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.005
        14      5    -10.000t      0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.007
        14     11     10.000t     -0.001      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.008
        15      6     32.845c      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.006
        15     11    -32.845c     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.000
        16      6    -53.223t      0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.012
        16     12     53.223t     -0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.010
        17      7     75.273c      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.008
        17     12    -75.273c     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.001
        18      8     16.142c      0.005      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.025
        18      9    -16.142c     -0.005      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.030
        19      9     89.682c      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.007
        19     10    -89.682c     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.008
        20     10     89.682c     -0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.009
        20     11    -89.682c      0.000      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.003
        21     11     53.228c     -0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.016
        21     12    -53.228c      0.002      0.0        0.0        0.0       -0.010
```

Is there any C# library that can be used to parse the information of this format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2008/03/18/importing-data-files-with-linq/) is a very interesting approach about importing tabulated data using Linq.

It's simple and elegant, you only need an Enumerable method that yields the lines from the file:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLinesFromFile(string filename)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string s = reader.ReadLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you do the query:

```
var jointDisplacements = from line in ReadLinesFromFile(@"c:\import.txt")
               let item = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' })
               select new
               {
              Joint = Convert.ToInt32(item[0]),
              X-dsp = Convert.ToDouble(item[1]),
              Y-dsp = Convert.ToDouble(item[2]),
              Z-dsp = Convert.ToDouble(item[3]),
              X-rot = Convert.ToDouble(item[4]),
              Y-rot = Convert.ToDouble(item[5]),
              Z-rot = Convert.ToDouble(item[6])
               };
```

You have now a list of [anonymous objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic15) that have the values from your file, represented as properties of each object.

If your file includes the column headers, you should skip the first line...

Answer (score 3):

No.

you could parse it yourself very easily using .NETs string library

eg  string.Split

Answer (score 1):

Regex could very well help.

Answer (score 1):

http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/ may be useful.  It won't be completely automatic. You'll need to do some work to break the different portions of the file into different streams that you can pass to the FileHelperEngine class that will parse the fixed format data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fixed length format?

With a bit of pre-processing, you could use an OLEDB driver to get the data out using standard APIs:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ReadTextFile.aspx

Someone created a sample that uses XML files to configure the format:

- https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6156780.html